# Designing a Template Database which can be efficiently re used for other same projects with minor changes

Tags: php, sql

I have experienced that mostly requirements are almost the same for different database projects. For e.g the databases of two different colleges or hospital are nearly the same. I was thinking is there some techniques that we can implement to design a template database which can be efficiently reused for other projects which have same requirement. All that we would have to do will be to change the design.It will also save a lot of time of the developer.
How can we design a database template which can be reused for other projects with minor changes? What things have to be generally kept in mind when designing/structuring such template?

Comment: As this isn't a specific question about a specific piece of code that isn't working properly, I'd suggest that this question is probably better suited to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have experienced that mostly requirements are almost the same for different database projects. For e.g the databases of two different colleges or hospital are nearly the same.

Normally, the rule for reusing stuff is to encapsulate what varies: determine which parts are the same, store that in a .SQL file, so you can reuse that over and over. I do note however; I've designed a lot of databases, ranging from software for administration, to simple websites, to webshops and I don't see a lot of overlap in the designs.

Comment: hmm thanks you mean that first i have to figure out the variations. then design the rest of database without those variations.And then reuse the designed database as template with just adding the changes as per project.